# Structs are giant. Why?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I am making a ripoff of minecraft and I am using a struct to store items, and just this:

```
typedef struct Item {
    union {
        struct {
            int V:4;
            int Q:6;
            int ID;
        } BItem;
        struct {
            union {
                struct {
                    int V:4;
                    int Q:6;
                    int ID;
                } BItem;
                struct {
                    int *Ench;
                    double Durability;
                    char *Name;
                    int ID;
                } TItem;
            } Item[4][8];
            enum {
                ICBItem,
                ICTItem
            } Type;
        } CItem;
        struct {
            int *Ench;
            double Durability;
            char *Name;
            int ID;
        } TItem;
    } ItemUnion;
    enum {
        BItem,
        CTtem,
        TItem
    } Type;
    void *UseHandler;
} Item;
```

I use sizeof on this and I get 1024 bytes. Just this should not take up so much memory. Can someone explain? I find this very frustrating and I want to store this into a file as a number using somehow casting the struct into an int using memcpy, but NO intager is big enough for a massive struct.

Comment: Take a look at `Item[4][8]`. That's 32 elements from that array. From the elements of it you get two pointers, a double and an int. You maybe get some padding bytes in there. Multiply all that by 32 and you get your "hugeness". This is all normal.

Comment: @DeiDei oh let me try something

Comment: Aside from the answers above, Is it normal to compose structs like this? It seems unmaintable and difficult to reason about. Why not decompose this into small, manageable units?

Comment: @DeiDei Wait. That actually makeys sense

Comment: The bitfields in `BItem` are pointless; in every situation in the overall type, a `BItem` is `union`-ed against something substantially larger: a `TItem` which contains two pointers, a `double` and an `int`.

Comment: Why should it "not take up so much memory"? How much memory should it take and why?

Comment: @Gerhardh that is basically the question

Comment: well, Not really. You claim it should not be that large as it is and you want to know why it is so large. But this means you expected it to be smaller. Youd did NOT tell us why you expected it to be smaller and how small. If you did expect the same size, you wouldn't have asked. For all questions if you get unexpected output, you should include what you expect and why.

Comment: *'store this into a file as a number using somehow casting the struct into an int using memcpy'* That does not really make sense though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
            } Item[4][8];
```

is 32 times the sizeof

```
            struct {
                int *Ench;
                double Durability;
                char *Name;
                int ID;
```

With int-pointer at 8 bytes and and double at 8 bytes and char pointer at 8 bytes and int at 4 bytes and some unknown padding to get the alignment correct, that may be 32 bytes. So 4 x 8 x 32 is 1024 bytes.

Try this code:

```
int main()
{
    Item x;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof x);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof x.ItemUnion.CItem);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0]);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0].TItem);

    printf("%p\n", (void*)&x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0].TItem.Ench);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0].TItem.Durability);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0].TItem.Name);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][0].TItem.ID);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&x.ItemUnion.CItem.Item[0][1].TItem.Ench);
    return 0;
}
```

On one plat form I get:

```
1048
1032
1024
32
32
0x7ffcdec7ea90  // Ench
0x7ffcdec7ea98  // Durability - 8 bytes later so Ench takes 8 bytes
0x7ffcdec7eaa0  // Name - 8 bytes later so Durability takes 8 bytes
0x7ffcdec7eaa8  // ID - 8 bytes later so Name takes 8 bytes
0x7ffcdec7eab0  // Ench of next element - 8 bytes later so ID takes 8 bytes
```

So we have 4 x 8 bytes which is 32 bytes. Some of these may be padding - most likely ID is really just 4 bytes followed by 4 bytes padding.